# How to get Mouse X and Y positions on click anywhere on the page?

Tags: javascript

Hello friends i want mouse X and Y position onclick anywhere on the webpage please help .i have tried this

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


var isNN = document.layers ? true : false;
var isIE = document.all ? true : false;

function init() {
  if ( isNN )
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
  document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
}

function handleMouseMove(evt) {
  mouseX = isNN ? evt.pageX : window.event.clientX;
  mouseY = isNN ? evt.pageY : window.event.clientY;
  window.status = "Mouse: X="+mouseX+",Y="+mouseY;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Google your question title + `javascript`. You will get many results.

Comment: Seriously? Like @Blender said try Google with the same thing and you would get your answer. Please put some effort into the question before posting.

Comment: Hello 2000. Where did you find that code?

Comment: Before resorting to Goole (or Bing, or Yahoo) you should start with the spec for DOM Events [interface MouseEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent) and then the related [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/MouseEvent) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974344(v=vs.85).aspx) references.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
        document.onclick = function(){
            X = document.Show.MouseX.value
            Y = document.Show.MouseY.value
            foo(X, Y);
        }
</script>
```